# Schurs Lemma for endomorphisms

Tags: representation-theory

Schur's lemma states that for an irrep $(\varphi,V)$ any endomorphism $\phi: V \mapsto V$ is given by a scalar mapping.

Lets say we are in the complex case, then this would mean:
$\phi = \lambda I$

Since any homomorphism between two representations is defined by its property $\varphi_1 = \phi^{-1} \varphi_2 \phi$, this would mean:

$\varphi_1 = (\lambda I)^{-1} \varphi_2 (\lambda I) = \varphi_2$

Therefore only a single irrep over $V$ exists, since $\varphi_1 = \varphi_2$.
What am I missing?

This should be false, since I found for the group $D_4$ at least two different irreps:
$$1:  \langle \{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \}\rangle$$
$$2:  \langle \{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \}\rangle$$

where $\phi$ should equal $\lambda I$, but for all $\lambda$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \ne (\lambda I)^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} (\lambda I).$$

Where goes everything wrong? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first two sentences you state versions of Schur's lemma involving an endomorphism $\phi$ (although the first statement is not correct unless you already assume yourself to be over an algebraically closed field). Starting from the third sentence you take $\phi$ to be a morphism, not an endomorphism. But what does it mean for a morphism between two representations to be multiplication by a scalar?

The correct version of Schur's lemma for a morphism between two irreducible repesentations is that the morphism must be either zero or invertible. It is zero if they are not isomorphic and invertible if they are. Note that in your second equation you assume that $\lambda \neq 0$.

Unitary has nothing to do with any of this.

Comment: You are right, Im talking about alg. cl. fields, I'm an engineer ;). I see that any morphism has to be zero or an iso (I assumed that the morphism is unequal 0 and therefore $\lambda \ne 0$, I should have stated that). However, I still have the same problem: If $\phi$ is an endo, $\phi = \lambda I$ is a scalar mapping (due to Schur's lemma). Is it right that $\lambda$ can either be $1$ or $-1$? Would that lead to different representations (that is what makes me headache).

Comment: Oh man, I feel really stupid now. You are totally right, I mixed stuff up like hell and simply misunderstood the lemma.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't the condition for two irreps to be equivalent require the transformation ($\phi$ in your case) to be unitary? If $|\lambda|\neq 1$, the corresonding transformation is non-unitary.

Comment: As far as I understand Schur's lemma, this would be true for an homomorphism $V \mapsto W$, where $V$ and $W$ may differ. The matrix would be $\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ in my example, so either my irreps are wrong or how the way I use Schur's lemma (in my example $V$ is the same with even the same basis).

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you mean by "this would be true?" Thanks

Comment: That would be the more general case of arbitrary vector spaces. The case $V \mapsto V$ is only a special case and following Schur's lemma, any representation homomorphism is given by a scalar mapping (which is indeed an isomorphism). "This would be true" was targeted at  your "the transformation ... to be unity".

Comment: If two representations are equivalent, they must be of the same dimension.

Comment: I didn't verify your irreps, but the mistake in your original argument is concluding from $\varphi_1 = \phi^{-1} \varphi_2 \phi$ that $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are equivalent. This holds if and only if $\phi$ is unitary.